# line 39: 'if' cannot be used as a variable or function name

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

Can anyone please help me understand what is the issue with the code I have written below.

My apologies, I am a new coder and I'm finding the debugging process to be difficult. The error I'm getting is in the Title.

line 39: 'if' cannot be used as a variable or function name.

```
//@version=5
strategy(title="Trend Following Strategy", overlay=true, pyramiding = true)

//Trend Filter Variables
ma_slow = ta.ema (close, 200) // moving average
ma_fast = ta.ema (close, 50) // moving average
ma_prev_high= ta.highest(ma_slow, 500) //Previous high of the EMA
trending_Market = ma_slow >= ma_prev_high//Current ma value is greater than previous ma value

//Trigger Condition
[macdLine, macdSig, macdHist ] = ta.macd(close, 12, 26, 9) // get MACD indicator
trigger = ma_fast > ma_slow and close > ma_slow and macdLine < 0 and macdSig <0 and macdLine > macdSig and macdHist[1] > 0 and macdHist[2] > 0

//Stop Loss Variables
prev_lows = ta.lowest(low, 150) //Price action Low
atr = ta.atr(14) //Average True Range - Stop Loss Buffer
price_stop = 0.0 //Stop initially set as null

//Long Condition
longCondition = trending_Market and trigger //go long if market is trending and trigger is hit
if (longCondition)
   strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)

//Once in the position declare the below variables
if (strategy.position_size> 0)
   
// Stop Loss Computation
   stopValue = prev_lows - atr //Stop loss value including ATR buffer
   price_stop := math.max(stopValue, price_stop[1] ) //Trailing condition for SL
   
else 
   price_stop := 0 // If no position set SL to null

//Conditions for entering a second position adjusting for risk already in the portfolio

//If trigger is hit while I have an open position and the trrailing SL has moved so that the position does not contain any risk 
//- then buy a full unit of risk
if (strategy.position_size> 0 and longCondition and math.avg(strategy.opentrades.entry_price(1),close)< price_stop)// If SL is above the average price of the 2 entries
   strategy.entry("long2_fullunit", strategy.long)


//If trigger is hit while I have an open position and SL is below the average price -
//i.e. there is still risk present from the initial position

if (strategy.position_size> 0 and longCondition and math.avg(strategy.opentrades.entry_price(1),close)> price_stop)// If SL is below the average price

//Declaraing Risk management variables
   avg_price = math.avg(strategy.opentrades.entry_price(1),close)//Average price of the initial entry and the current price at which the second postion will execute
   lot2 = (avg_price/(avg_price - price_stop))*10000// Lot size per 1 unit of risk at current SL and average price
   lot2_qty = lot2/close //Investment amount in share quantity
   risk_adjusted_qty = lot2 - strategy.position_size // The difference in the proposed quantity of shares to purchase in the second postion and thequantity of shares already held
   
   
   strategy.entry("long2_risk_adjusted_unit", strategy.long, qty = risk_adjusted_qty ) // enter the second trade at a risk adjusted ammount, keeping risk always at 1R.


//exit condition   
if (strategy.position_size>0) //apply the exit strategy with variables declared upon entry
   strategy.exit(id= "Stop Loss", stop= price_stop  )
```

Answer (score 0):

The local blocks in conditional structures must be indented by four spaces or a tab. You have three spaces as far as I can see and if I fix those indentation issues, there are no errors.

```
//@version=5
strategy(title="Trend Following Strategy", overlay=true, pyramiding = true)

//Trend Filter Variables
ma_slow = ta.ema (close, 200) // moving average
ma_fast = ta.ema (close, 50) // moving average
ma_prev_high= ta.highest(ma_slow, 500) //Previous high of the EMA
trending_Market = ma_slow >= ma_prev_high//Current ma value is greater than previous ma value

//Trigger Condition
[macdLine, macdSig, macdHist ] = ta.macd(close, 12, 26, 9) // get MACD indicator
trigger = ma_fast > ma_slow and close > ma_slow and macdLine < 0 and macdSig <0 and macdLine > macdSig and macdHist[1] > 0 and macdHist[2] > 0

//Stop Loss Variables
prev_lows = ta.lowest(low, 150) //Price action Low
atr = ta.atr(14) //Average True Range - Stop Loss Buffer
price_stop = 0.0 //Stop initially set as null

//Long Condition
longCondition = trending_Market and trigger //go long if market is trending and trigger is hit
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)

//Once in the position declare the below variables
if (strategy.position_size> 0)
   
// Stop Loss Computation
    stopValue = prev_lows - atr //Stop loss value including ATR buffer
    price_stop := math.max(stopValue, price_stop[1] ) //Trailing condition for SL
   
else 
    price_stop := 0 // If no position set SL to null

//Conditions for entering a second position adjusting for risk already in the portfolio

//If trigger is hit while I have an open position and the trrailing SL has moved so that the position does not contain any risk 
//- then buy a full unit of risk
if (strategy.position_size> 0 and longCondition and math.avg(strategy.opentrades.entry_price(1),close)< price_stop)// If SL is above the average price of the 2 entries
    strategy.entry("long2_fullunit", strategy.long)


//If trigger is hit while I have an open position and SL is below the average price -
//i.e. there is still risk present from the initial position

if (strategy.position_size> 0 and longCondition and math.avg(strategy.opentrades.entry_price(1),close)> price_stop)// If SL is below the average price

//Declaraing Risk management variables
    avg_price = math.avg(strategy.opentrades.entry_price(1),close)//Average price of the initial entry and the current price at which the second postion will execute
    lot2 = (avg_price/(avg_price - price_stop))*10000// Lot size per 1 unit of risk at current SL and average price
    lot2_qty = lot2/close //Investment amount in share quantity
    risk_adjusted_qty = lot2 - strategy.position_size // The difference in the proposed quantity of shares to purchase in the second postion and thequantity of shares already held
    strategy.entry("long2_risk_adjusted_unit", strategy.long, qty = risk_adjusted_qty ) // enter the second trade at a risk adjusted ammount, keeping risk always at 1R.


//exit condition   
if (strategy.position_size>0) //apply the exit strategy with variables declared upon entry
    strategy.exit(id= "Stop Loss", stop= price_stop  )
```